# How to return a function result into query?

Tags: postgresql

I have a function called **ClientStatus** that returns a record with two fields **Status_Description** and **Status_Date**. This function receives a parameter **Client_Id**.
I'm trying to get the calculated client status for all the clients in the table **Clients**, something like:

```
| Client_Name | Status_Description | Status_Date |
+-------------+--------------------+-------------+
| Abc         | Active             | 12-12-2010  |
| Def         | Inactive           | 13-12-2011  |
```

Where **Client_Name** comes from the table **Clients**, **Status_Description** and **Status_Date** from the function result.

My first (wrong) approach was to join the table and the function like so:

```
SELECT c.Client_Name, cs.Status_Description, cs.Status_Date FROM Clients c
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT * FROM ClientStatus(c.ClientId) as (Status_Description text, Status_Date date)) cs
```

This obviously didn't work because **c.ClientId** could not be referenced.

Could someone explain me how can I obtain the result I am looking for?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following can give the result you expect :

```
SELECT c.Client_Name, d.Status_Description, d.Status_Date 
FROM Clients c, ClientStatus(c.ClientId) d
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, it works but the function is called twice making the query slower than it should be.

Comment: And this one ? SELECT c.Client_Name, d.Status_Description, d.Status_Date FROM Clients c, ClientStatus(c.ClientId) d

Comment: You are right! :) That is a much better solution. Could you post that as an answer? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem writing the query like this:

```
SELECT c.Client_Name, cs.status[1] as Description, cs.stautus[2]::date as Date
FROM (
  SELECT string_to_array(translate(
    (SELECT ClientStatus(ClientId))::Text, '()', ''),  ',') status
  FROM Clients
) cs
```

It is not the most elegant solution but it was the only one I could find to make this work.